# Box Search API - Does it support regex?

Tags: box-api

I am referring to Search API below.
https://box-content.readme.io/#searching-for-content

I want to know if "query" parameter supports regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

*(...extra characters to make answer longer...)*

Comment: To the downvoter: have you reached a different conclusion?